# Maven project with prebuilt jar

Tags: maven

Currently I am not using Maven in any way whatsoever, but since I am writing a library I would like other developers to be able to use it as a Maven dependency. It seems like the easiest way to do this would be to have a Maven project which just contains the jar.

However, all the examples I've seen of pom.xml have build logic in them and I was wondering how I am supposed specify the prebuilt jar as the resulting artifact.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understand you correctly, so maybe I am commenting something totally different.

If you want to offer your project as Maven dependency for other projects, the project must be somewhere to be downloaded (Maven central repository, your company Nexus...) and your project must have something to identify it: groupId, artifactId and the version. You can specify these separately when installing the artifact, or you can provide a pom that contains this metadata, along with dependencies if there are any. Both approaches are explained [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).

Then adding something like this in the project that wants your project as dependency, it should work.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>group-a</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Still, since you control this project, you might want to consider converting your library to a Maven project to reap other benefits of Maven (in some IDEs like Eclipse there is an option that convert a regular Java Project in a Maven project), and in the generated pom.xml is the info which is mention above.

Here an example of a basic pom.xml to be a jar.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Maven Quick Start Archetype</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Extracted from here --> http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. So what you describe is basically what I want. The part which I am confused on is what to put in pom.xml to say that I want the build artifact to be some jar

Comment: @RichardFung see the added example

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. Am I supposed to just put the jar into the same directory as pom.xml? Also it seems like there's no need to have the dependencies block there right since I'm not going to be running any tests through Maven

Comment: First, I recomend you to read the Maven documentation. Second, the library jar is 'installed' in your computer in .m2 folder, and when you put as dependency in other project in the pom.xml of this new project, the library jar is added automatically when you build the new project with maven, you only need to add that dependency in the pom.xml

Comment: I have been reading the documentation but most of it is geared towards building. Also, I dont need a library for myself to build, I need to put it in a repository so other developers can use it. In any case I figured it out, I just need to use one of the deploy plugins. Thanks!